# Issue with saving value to shared preferences from Firebase ID

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences, firebase-authentication

I'm using a firebase ID as my user ID on my backend database.  In my opening activity, I check for a firebase ID, then save it to shared preferences.  Only with a firebase ID should you be able to proceed.

The issue is that now I'm proceeding to the next screen, and the firebase ID is not being saved to the shared preferences.  I'm using the following firebase libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
```

Here is the code that I'm using in the onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    cp = AmazonS3.getProvider(context);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
    quizImage.clear();
    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    res = getResources();
    setContentView(R.layout.loadingscreen);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    spEditor = sp.edit();

    cognitioID = sp.getString("Cognito","");
    firebaseID = sp.getString("Firebase", "");
   // String userID = sp.getString("USERID", "");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "firebaseID: " + firebaseID);

    if (cognitioID == "") {
        new cognitoID().execute();
    }
    shouldGoToMainActivity = false;
    numberOfDownloadedFiles = 0;



     if(sp.getString("Firebase","").isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "splash activity no firebase ID");

        configureGoogleSignIn();

        LoginButton fbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        fbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        //Login with Facebook and volley write to users.php
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        fbLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends", "email", "user_location"));

        fbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Facebook Login Success");
                fbAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

//Make the Call to below method to get and set firebase ID

                firebaseAuthWithFacebook(fbAccessToken);

                final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        fbAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Facebook graph reqest "+ response + "");
                                fbUser = object;


                                try {
                                    fullName = object.getString("name");
                                    firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                                    lastName = object.getString("last_name");
                                    email = object.getString("email");
                                    ageRange = object.getString("age_range");
                                    gender = object.getString("gender");
                                    userid = firebaseID;
                                    Utils.getZipCodeForCurrentLocation(context)
                                            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void call(String s) {
                                                    zip = s;
                                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Zip code in Facebook: " + s);

                                                }
                                            });

                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "name from fb graph/age "+ fullName +" "+ ageRange);
                                    Log.i("fb id", userid);
                                    spEditor.putString("firstName", firstName);
                                    spEditor.putString("lastName", lastName);
                                    spEditor.putString("fullName", fullName);
                                    spEditor.putString("email", email);
                                    spEditor.putString("Firebase", userid);
                                    spEditor.putString("zip", zip);

                                    spEditor.commit();

                                    uploadUserInfo();

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        });

                Bundle fbparameters = new Bundle();
                fbparameters.putString("fields", "name, email, age_range, gender, first_name, last_name ");
                request.setParameters(fbparameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Facebook SignIn Error, please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                snackbar.show();
                Log.d("facebook Login", "facebook error - " + error);
            }

        });

    }

    else {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, firebaseID + " is assigned and written");
        shouldGoToMainActivity = true;
    }


     firebaseListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null){
                //Authenticated with Firebase
                firebaseID = firebaseUser.getUid();
                spEditor.putString("Firebase", userid);
                spEditor.commit();
                Log.i("Splash Firebase", "onAuthStateChanged: signed_in:  " + firebaseUser.getUid());
            } else{
                Log.i("Splash Firebase", "onAuthStateChanged: signed_out");
            }
        }
    };

    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseListener);

    //end of OnCreate
    }



     @Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if (firebaseAuth != null){
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseListener);
    }
}


 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RC_RESOLVE_ERROR){

        intentInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            isSignedIn = false;
            //Maybe show a dialog to user ?
            return;
        }
        //Attemp connection again.
        if (googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(intent);
        handleGoogleSignInResult(result);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}


  /**
 * setup Google Api client and signInButton
 */
private void configureGoogleSignIn(){
    googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();

    SignInButton gLogin = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.g_login_button);
    gLogin.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    gLogin.setScopes(new Scope[]{Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN});
    //  gLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    gLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signInByGPlus();
        }
    });
    gLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


private void signInByGPlus(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GPLUS_SIGN_IN);
}

/**
 * Save userId and user's full name if login successful. If not, main screen will be
 * started anyway (as a guest)
 * @param result
 */
private void handleGoogleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result){
    if (null == result){
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "login result is null (user canceled login - proceed as a guest)");
        return;
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleGoogleSignInResult (is successful?): " + result.isSuccess());
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()){
        isSignedIn = false;
        intentInProgress = false;
        GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(googleAccount);
        if(result.getStatus().hasResolution()||result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED){
            freshSignIn();


        }

    }
    else {
        intentInProgress = false;
        isSignedIn = true;
        acct = result.getSignInAccount();

    }



    fullName = acct.getDisplayName();
    email = acct.getEmail();
    userid = firebaseID;
    /** google+ return fullname in format first name " " last name */
    String[] nameParts = fullName.split(" ");
    if (nameParts.length == 2){
        firstName = nameParts[0];
        lastName = nameParts[1];
    }else {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
    }
    /** Google has no idea about gender */
    gender = "";

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "full name: " + fullName);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "first name: " + firstName);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "last name: " + lastName);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "email: " + email);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "id: " + userid);

    spEditor.putString("firstName", firstName);
    spEditor.putString("lastName", lastName);
    spEditor.putString("fullName", fullName);
    spEditor.putString("Firebase", firebaseID);

    spEditor.putString("email", email);

    Utils.getZipCodeForCurrentLocation(this)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    zip = s;
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Zip code: " + s);
                    spEditor.putString("zip", s);
                    uploadUserInfo();
                }
            });
    spEditor.commit();
}


private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct){
    Log.d("SplashActivity firebase", "firebaseAuthWtihGoogle: "+ acct.getId());
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    firebaseID = user.getUid();
    spEditor.putString("Firebase", firebaseID);
    spEditor.commit();


    AuthCredential firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("SpalshActivity firebase", "signInwithCredential: onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.w("SplashActivity firebase", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    shouldGoToMainActivity = true;
}

private void firebaseAuthWithFacebook(AccessToken token){
    Log.d("SPlash Firebase Face", "firebaseAuthWithFacebook:" + token);
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    firebaseID = user.getUid();
    spEditor.putString("Firebase", firebaseID);
    spEditor.commit();


    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
               .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                       Log.d("Splash Firebase Face", "signInWithCredential[FB]:onComplete: " + task.isSuccessful());

                       if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                           Log.w("Splash Firebase Face", "signInWithCredential[FB]" + task.getException());
                           Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Authentication Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
               });

    shouldGoToMainActivity = true;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `sharedPreference` to indicate if user is logged in or not? You can simply use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`. As it will return `null` if user is not logged in

Comment: I'm using the firebase ID as a key in the other activities, so I need to save it somewhere to write to and from databases, etc.